# Angular2 IE11 & Safari ng-if and routing issue

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, components

I have added polyfills:

```
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
```

and uncomment all polyfills in polyfills.ts

1) When move to another page - old components still live below the page
2) Even components with ngIf - once appeared - still live on the page

UPD: Similar issue for Safari & IE, rest of browsers works good

Comment: does it work with chrome , as i feel it more a problem with `router-outlet`

Comment: Works good in Chrome, FF, Safari. Not sure router-outlet issue. NgIf doesn't works good too